# react-native-navigation theming with styled-components

Tags: react-native, styled-components, react-native-navigation

I'm working with [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) on my react-native project. We are using [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) to perform navigation within the application. So the question is how can I implement theme pattern from styled-components in such kind of application?
The problem is that to perform the idea of theming in terms of styled-components I have to wrap my top level component in `<ThemeProvider />` like this:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <App />
</ThemeProvider>
```

But with react-native-navigation I don't have top level component. It has the idea of screens, so the application entry will look like this:

```
registerScreens(); // this is where you register all of your app's screens

// start the app
Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
  screen: { ... },
  drawer: { ... },
  passProps: { ... },
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple. As react-native-navigation's registerComponent has possibility to pass redux store and Provider as a props:

```
Navigation.registerComponent('UNIQUE_ID', () => YourComponent, store, Provider);
```

We can create our custom Provider with both redux and styled-components Providers and pass this custom provider to the registerComponent like this:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import theme from './theme';

const Provider = ({ store, children }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  </Provider>
);

export default Provider;
```

For more details look [#1920](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/1920).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this

```
function wrap(Component) {
    return function () {
        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Component />
                <AnotherComponent/>
            </ThemeProvider>
        );
    };
}

function registerScreens(store, Provider) {
    Navigation.registerComponent('app.SomeScreen', () =>  wrap(SomeScreen), store, Provider);
    // more screens...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is definitely the option, but it means that I have to wrap all the screens with this HOC. I was searching for some solution like it is made for redux Provider. And there is a way to do it. (Look [#1920](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/1920))